# How to handle the options "Sorry, no matching options" hanging when click on the vue select with empty options?

Tags: vue.js

I create the select option with vue-select. But, I have an issue on the behaviour of vue-select when it's empty, it show message "Sorry, no options matching".

HTML Code:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Custom Labels</h1>
  <v-select label="countryName" :options="options"></v-select>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2c3e5099;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#app {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

JS Code:

```
Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: null
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/aEjLPB

Make a data, options: null

The dropdown will show the message "Sorry, no options matching".
Click on that options, and the dropdown select will hanging.

I expect the dropdwon select will close when select the "Sorry, no options matching".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vue-select` allows slots, I found a list of slots in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/oZmLVN)

So you can use the slot for **no-options** found, and close the select when that element is clicked by using `ref` and `$refs`. I found more info on how to close `v-select` in this [github issue](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/276#issuecomment-321620931)

```
<v-select ref="select">
  <span slot="no-options" @click="$refs.select.open = false">
    Sorry, no matching options
  </span>
</v-select>
```